# Data Factory Expression - get a sas token from JSON

Tags: azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

I have an output from web activity in Azure Data Factory which generate a JSON containing SAS token for blob storage.
I need to pass this SAS Token as an URL to an other Web Activity after every run, as it will expired after 5 minutes.

output example in JSON:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"https://<baseurl>/data/$metadata#Edm.String",
    "value": "{\"BlobId\":\"{<GUID>}\",\"BlobUrl\":\"https://<baseurl_id>.blob.core.windows.net/dmf/<uniqueFileName>?<SAS Token>\"}"    
}
}
```

The part that needs to be extracted:

`https://<baseurl_id>.blob.core.windows.net/dmf/<uniqueFileName>?<SAS Token>`

so far I tried this, by using dynamics content in second web activity:

`@activity('web').output.value['BlobUrl']`

Could you please support?

Comment: try @json(activity('web').output.value).BlobUrl , I usually use a SetVariable for testing if I am getting the proper value extracted.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger thanks a lot - it works! And really great advise for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
@json(activity('web').output.value).BlobUrl
```

'value' is serialized json, you convert 'value' it to json with the @json function.  Then you can access any of the properties easily as .BlobUrl shown above.

Whenever I am not sure how to extract a certain value from an output I use the SetVariable activity for testing, it can be removed once you have it figured it out.